# Nativescript Angular 2 - Add class to label on click

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I want to implement a like button (like in instagram, twitter etc) in my nativescript angular 2 app. clicking on the label should add the "active" class to the label. After clicking it again, it should remove the "active" class.

home.component.html

```
<label text="{{ post.likes }}" class="" (tap)="like()">
```

home.component.html (after clicking the label)

```
<label text="{{ post.likes }}" class="active" (tap)="like()>
```

home.component.ts

```
like() {
    if (/* post contains "active" class */) {
        // remove "active" class to label
    } else {
        // add "active" class to label
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toggle css class on clicked element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016451/toggle-css-class-on-clicked-element-only)

Comment: Make sure you use `Label` with uppercase `L`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) here.

```
<Label text="{{ post.likes }}" [ngClass]="liked ? 'active' : ''" (tap)="like()></Label>
```

and in your home.component.ts

```
like() {
//toggle this.liked here.
}
```

Comment: Could just use `(tap)="liked = !liked"`, don't need a method for something so simple. Also be sure to declare the variable in the component, `public liked: boolean;`, or as an `Input()` if this is used as a child component.

Comment: Yes, that could be done but I have added that in like function assuming OP may want to do few more things on Label click.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the variable which store if it liked or not. Accordingly, it will add the class or remove the class from the element
Example:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-element',
    template: '<div [class.liked]="post.liked">Hello Post <button (tap)="toggleLiked(post)"></button> </div>',
    styles: [`
       .liked {
           color: red
       }
    `]

})
export class AppComponent {
    liked = false;
    toggleLiked(post): void {
       post.liked = !post.liked;
    }
}
```

Note: Works because object referance.
Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkravu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html